# push notification not working on android 12 and 13

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ionic6, cordova-plugin-fcm

i am using push notification in my ionic cordova project and it's working on every android versions except android 12 and 13. How can i fix it?

this is how my androidmanifest.xml looks

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="27" android:versionName="0.27.0" package="com.travidux.mygian" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application android:exported="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.sarriaroman.PhotoViewer.PhotoActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="true" android:label="@string/launcher_name" android:name=".Block_All_Notification" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, did you replace "your.package.name" with the right name?